# 複数ページでセッション変数を利用する

Tags: php

1枚目のページinput.phpの次へボタンを押し、
2枚目のページdogcat.phpの確認ボタンを押すと、
3枚目のページconfirm2.phpがNot Found
The requested URL /confirm2.php was not found on this server.
になります。ドキュメントルートもファイル保存場所も1枚目と2枚目のページと同じ
場所なのに何故confirm2.phpだけNot Foundになるのでしょうか。
お手すきの際で結構ですので、ご確認頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

input.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>入力ページ</title>
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    アンケート(1/2) <br>
 <form method="POST" action="dogcat.php">
    <ul>
       <li><label>名前:
           <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="ニックネーム可" value="<?php echo es($name) ?>" ;>
       </label></li>
       <li><label>好きな言葉:
          <input type="text" name="kotoba" value="<?php echo es($kotoba) ?>" ;>
        </label></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="次へ"></li>
    </ul>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

dogcart.php

```
<?php
//セッションの開始
session_start();
require_once("util.php");

//$_POST変数に値があればセッション変数に受け渡す
if (isset($_POST[ 'name' ])) {
   $_SESSION[ 'name' ] = $_POST[ 'name' ];
 }
if (isset($_POST[ 'kotoba' ])) { 
   $_SESSION[ 'kotoba' ] = $_POST[ 'kotoba' ];
 }
//セッション変数に値があれば受け渡す
if (empty($_SESSION[ 'dogcat' ])) {
    $dagcat = [];
 } else {
$dogcat = $_SESSION[ 'dogcat' ];
}
?>

<?php
//初期値でチェックするかどうか
 function checked($value, $question) {
    if (is_array($question)) {
        //配列の時、値が含まれていればtrue
    $isChecked = in_array($value, $question);
    } else {
        //配列ではない時、値が一致すればtrue
 $isChecked = ($value===$question);
 }
 if ($isChecked) {
    //チェックする
    echo "checked";
 } else {
    echo "";
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>犬好き猫好きページ</title>
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
 アンケート(2/2) <br>
 <form method="POST" action="confirm2.php">
    <ul>
        <li><span>犬が好きですか？猫が好きですか？</span><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="dogcat[]" value="犬" <?php checked("犬", $dogcat); ?> >犬が好き</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="dogcat[]" value="猫" <?php checked("猫", $dogcat); ?> >猫が好き</label>
　　<li>
       <input type="button" value="戻る" onclick="location.href='input.php' ">
       <input type="submit" value="確認する" >
    </ul>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

confirm2.php

```
<?php
  //セッションの開始
session_start();
require_once("util.php");
?>

<?php
  //文字エンコードの検証
if (!cken($_POST)) {
 $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
 $err = "Encoding Error! The expected encoding is " . $encoding;
 $isError = true;
  //エラーメッセージを出して、以下のコードを全てキャンセルする
  exit($err);
  }
?>

  <?php
   //入力データの取り出しとチェック
 $error = [];
  //セッション変数に値があれば受け渡す
  if (empty($_SESSION[ 'name' ])) {
     $error[] = "名前を入力して下さい。";
  } else {
    $name = $_SESSION[ 'name' ];
}
if (empty($_SESSION[ 'kotoba' ])) {
    $error[] = "好きな言葉を入力して下さい。";
} else {
    $kotoba = $_SESSION[ 'kotoba' ];
}

  //POSTされた値をセッション変数に受け渡す
  if (isset($_POST[ 'dogcat' ])) {
 $dogcat = $_POST[ 'dogcat' ];    
 $_SESSION[ 'dogcat' ] = $dagcat;
 //値のチェック
 $diffValue = array_diff($dogcat, ["犬","猫"]);
 //規定外の値が含まれていなければok
 if (count($diffValue)>0) {
       $error[] = "犬好き猫好きの回答にエラーがありました。";
}
$dogcatString = implode("好きで、", $dagcat) . "好きです。";
} else {
$dogcatString = "どちらも好きではありません。";
$_SESSION[ 'dogcat' ] = [];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>確認ページ</title>
  <link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form>
<?php if(count($error)>0 ) { ?>

 <span class="error"><?php echo implode('<br>', $error); ?></span><br>
<span>
    <input type="button" value="戻る"  onclick="locaton.href='input.php' ">
</span>
<?php } else { ?>

<span>
 名前:<?php echo es($name); ?><br>
 好きな言葉:<?php echo es($kotoba); ?><br>
 犬猫好き？:<?php echo es($dogcatString); ?><br>
<input type="button" value="訂正する" onclick="location.href='input.php' ">
<input type="button" value="送信する" onclick="location.href='thankyou2.php' ">
</span>
<?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thankyou2.php

```
<?php
require_once("util.php");
  //セッションの開始
session_start();
//セッションのチェック
$error = [];
if (!empty($_SESSION[ 'name' ]) && !empty($_SESSION[ 'kotoba' ])) {
 //セッション変数から値を取り出す
$name = $_SESSION[ 'name' ];
$kotoba = $_SESSION[ 'kotoba' ];
$dogcat = $_SESSION[ 'dogcat' ];
$dogcatString = implode("好きで、", $dogcat) . "好きです。";
} else {
    //セッション変数が空だった時
   $error[] = "セッションエラーです。";
}
//HTMLを表示する前にセッションを終了する
killSession()
?>

<?php
//セッションを破棄する
function killSession() {
//セッション変数の値を空にする
$_SESSION = [];
//セッションクッキーを破棄する
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
   $params = session_get_cookie_params();
   setcookie(session_name(), ' ', time()-36000, $params[ 'path' ]);
   }
  //セッションを破棄する
  session_destroy();
  }
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>完了ページ</title>
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <?php if (count($error)>0) { ?>

   <span class="error"><?php echo implode('<br>' , $error); ?></span><br> 
   <span>
     <input type="button" value="最初のページに戻る" onclick="location.href='input.php' ">
   </span>
   <?php } else { ?>

      次のように受付けました。ありがとうございました。
      <HR>
      <span>
      名前:<?php echo es($name); ?><br>
      好きな言葉:<?php echo es($kotoba); ?><br>
      犬猫好き？:<?php echo es($dogcatString); ?><br>
      <a href="input.php" >最初のページに戻る</a>
      </span>
        <?php } ?>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

エラーコード

```
[31-Jul-2018 07:41:15 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dogcat in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dogcat.php on line 53
[31-Jul-2018 07:41:15 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dogcat in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dogcat.php on line 54

[31-Jul-2018 07:43:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dogcat in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thankyou2.php on line 11
[31-Jul-2018 07:43:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thankyou2.php on line 12
```

Comment: タイトルは「質問の内容」を表すようにしてください。プログラムでセッション変数は使用されているのかもしれませんが、実際のエラー内容は「ファイルが見つからない」のはずです。

Comment: すいません。今後はタイトルのつけ方をもう少し考えていきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FORMタグでACTIONの指定先を絶対パス、または相対パスで明示してみてください。

例：　すべてのファイルが同じディレクトリに存在するなら`./`を追加 (相対パス)

```
<form method="POST" action="./confirm2.php">
```

または絶対パスで指定

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/confirm2.php">
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。相対パスも絶対パスも試しましたがまだ404のままです。迷宮です。

Comment: 質問文だと説明テキストですが`dogcart`になっています。あっているつもりでもファイル名をもう一度よく確認してください。また、質問が解決してから「承認済み」としてください。

Comment: confirm.phpをcomfirm.phpで名前をつけてたのが原因でした。お騒がせしてすいません。